# combining ycbcr components matlab

Tags: matlab

I converted an 240 x 320 RGB image to YCbCr and I separated the Y,Cb and Cr components and did some processing.Then I used the command

`A=cat(3,E(:,:,1),E(:,:,2),E(:,:,3));`

to combine the Y,Cb and Cr components where `E` is the matrix that contains the components.The 3 dimensions of `E` are of size 240 x 320 and many pixels in `E` are close to the value 128.Instead of displaying the image,a white box is displayed when I use the command

`figure,imshow(A);`

What is the error in the above code?

Comment: Have you tried to check the range of the Image if is suitable? And what about the datatype? You may have change it with your processing, you may want to cast it back to uint8.  What happens if you call      figure,imshow(A,[]);  ?  (note I've added the [] after A)

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to display doubles, try to convert it back to uint8

Comment: Thank you :) I converted it to uint8 and it worked :)

Comment: You're welcome, is a common mistake one does :)